# Ubuntu Openstack cloud-installer error: kvm container creation failed

Tags: virtualization, juju, kvm-virtualization, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to install OpenStack on an older server using the Ubuntu cloud-installer. I have virtualization enabled in BIOS and kvm-ok tells me that I'm good to use KVM with acceleration.

```
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

The Dashboard keeps showing a message that it's "Allocating" a new machine, which is immediately followed by this message

```
[INFO] ? Waiting for a machine. Machines summary: 18 unknown (error: kvm container creation failed: exit
status 1), 1 unknown
```

The number (18 above) increments each time. Any idea how to get around this or troubleshoot it?

Comment: What do you mean by "older server", if it is beyond end of life it is not supported, you will have to upgrade. Second, this sounds like a bug report and it is difficult to advise you without additional information. That error message is not helping, simply stating something is not working does not give us much to go on.

Comment: It has some older processors http://ark.intel.com/products/33081/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5430-12M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB. I'm not sure if it's a bug report. I just know that it was throwing that error and I couldn't find any more information. I tried a "cloud-install -u" and then ran it again and now it's not doing anything. I'm not sure where to find additional information

Comment: Here's the full error that keeps repeating `DEBUG • 09-25 11:32:31 [LINE:288, FUNC:get_controller_machine] • cloudinstall.core • Allocated machines: [<Machine(,,N/A,N/A,N/A)>]
INFO • 09-25 11:32:31 [LINE:96, FUNC:info_message] • cloudinstall.core • Waiting for a machine. Machines summary: 1 unknown, 1 unknown (error: kvm container creation failed: exit status 1)
`

Comment: Thank you for adding that information. If you do not get an answer "soon" I suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: I just tried it on a very modern system with the latest processors and I get the same errors, so it's not the old processors causing it.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed with the latest packages in the testing ppa. Basically, we are dependent on the `qemu-kvm` package which wasn't installed by default for use with `virtinst`. Here is the associated bug for this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1387881

So far I've gotten positive results from other testers who were able to continue once `qemu-kvm` package was installed on their system running the installer.